# Reuse artifacts from previous pipelines in Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines, artifacts

I would like to use an artifact from a previous pipeline and checking the documentation I haven't been able to find how.

I've only seen how to reuse them in the same pipeline (https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/using-artifacts-in-steps-935389074.html)

How can I reuse an existing artifact from a previous pipeline?

This is my current bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
image: php:7.2.18

pipelines:
   branches:
      delete-me:
        - step:
            name: Build docker containers
            artifacts:
              - docker_containers.tar
            services:
              - docker
            script:
              - docker/build_containers_if_not_exists.sh
              - sleep 30 # wait for docker to start all containers
              - docker save $(docker images -q) -o ${BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR}/docker_containers.tar
        - step:
            name: Compile styles & js
            caches:
              - composer
            script:
              - docker load --input docker_containers.tar
              - docker-compose up -d
              - composer install
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use Pipelines Caches feature. You should define your custom cache, for example:

```
definitions:
  caches:
    docker_containers: /docker_containers
```

The cache will be saved after the first successful build and will be available to the next pipelines for the next 7 days. Here is more info about using caches https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/caching-dependencies-895552876.html

Comment: gosh, i didn't see it has docker cache predefined., ty!